# Wrote a song/has written a song

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

There is a sentence:

- She **has written** /**wrote a song** for him
  (without any additional information)
  Am I right by thinking that the variant of this sentence is more correct with ***Present perfect (has written)*** because the result is relevant now?

But I'd also like to inquire about the use of ***past simple*** in this sentence. Will it be correct?

Comment: Without any additional information, it's impossible to say whether one version is "more correct" than the other.  It is only context that makes the difference.  "Relevant now" is not really a useful rule: "Joe Biden was elected president of the US" is "relevant" now, but that doesn't mean that "has been elected" is always the correct form now.  Have you read any references on the difference between past simple and present perfect?

Comment: Yes, I have. The example with the president is like the fact in the past, that's why past simple is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Wrote" is the *simple past* form, and means written any time in the past.
- "Has written" is the *present perfect* form, and means that the writing is completed.

They both refer to an action in the past, and in many contexts, these two forms are almost interchangeable.

For example:

- I saw that movie
- I have seen that movie

I wouldn't consider there to be any discernable difference in meaning between the two above examples.

However, with your example, the latter sounds like it is the *recent past*.

Here are some examples in a similar context to yours to explain how it works in practice:

> -Paul McCartney wrote a song called 'Yesterday'.
> -Yes, I believe he wrote that in 1965.

'Wrote' sounds like it is firmly in the past. But:

> -Paul McCartney has written a song called 'Yesterday'.
> -What, another? Didn't he write one called that in 1965?

"Has written" sounds like it is recent history. I would consider this implication before you choose which to use.